# facilitators viewing registration responses

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, civireport

We have co-facilitators for our instructional events who are not staff. We want them to be able to view the complete registration profile responses (i.e. 'registration info') prior to their event in order to know how many and who are registered, plan the event content based on registration responses, etc. There may be several events concurrently registering, with different facilitators.

We have created the custom fields and registration profiles and a report that shows responses, and that is working well. Just not sure how to have others view it. Event registration includes some questions common to all events (contact-level), and some custom fields that are event-specific (i.e. participant, not contact, level- such as previous experience with the topic, contexts in which they use the topic, familiarity with the content, etc.)

What's the best way to do this? I am a non-developer user and we don't have IT staff.

Ideas for how to do this include:
a) creating a 'facilitator' role (Drupal 7), which would include permissions to view only the report that contains that event's registration info. Not sure how to do this, might require ACL's?

b) customizing the participant listing to include event-specific registration responses, and sending the link to that. Not sure how to do this, but can look into it if this is the way to go.

c) ?is there a way to get a checksum or profile link that would say ‘here’s our registration’ with an expiration date

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest non-IT solution is to create a participant report in CiviCRM with the information you need and then under Actions, Export it and email it to them.

The next option would be to do as you described with Drupal Roles and [ACLs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/). The down side is the learning curve for them to learn to filter and sort the Civi Reports to get the data they need.  In the ACL settings you will probably need to give them access to everything that Donors have access to plus: CiviCRM view all contacts, CiviCRM view all activities, CiviCRM access backend and API, CiviCRM access CiviEvents, (depending on the level of access you want you can give the edit events), CiviCRM acess Report criteria (so they can change the filter/sort/group)

The third easiest would be to use [CiviCRM WebForm Integration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) Create your event registration form with Webform. You will then have several easy options to get them the registrations. a) You can give the "Facilitators" access to the Webform Submissions, b) you can set the submission emails so that a copy of the registration is sent to them when it is submitted, c) you can schedule a regular submission results (weekly, monthly) to be emailed to them, d) you can download the results and email it to them.

Another way is to create [Drupal View page](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/) with this information on it. You can create a Drupal Role of "Facilitator" and restrict access to the page to Admin & Facilitator. This option would give you a url that they can access to see and sort the data as they need.

Comment: I was going to post an Answer with the Drupal Views solution. Since it is already here I will just try to give that a (thumbs up)

Comment: Thanks for the options!
1. Export- We'll have 11 events &12 facilitators- exports (daily near the event) would be too time-consuming.
2. Drupal roles, permissions and ACL's. ***Is there a way I can give them permission to JUST view the report that I have already designed?*** I don't want them being able to click around and view everything else. 
3. Webform & 4. Drupal Views -> I will soon have this exact Q for a WordPress site, so I'd love to use permissions. I'll play around with Drupal Views and see what I can figure out (e.g. what permissions to JUST be able to see that view?)

Comment: For #2, with the list I gave that you likely need to give permission to in ACL, that should just give them access to the event reports. Depending on if they need to see contact info, you might not want to include the "View all Contacts". In general, as long as you give View or Access, they do not have edit abilities.